# What is the best way to persist data between several views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an MVC 5 application and have the following scenario. 
The user clicks my registration link to create an account and is served with a view like so. Works as expected.

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult RenderRegisterModal(string userType)
{
    IList<UserTypesDto> userTypes = _userService.GetUserTypes();

    var usersRegisterUserViewModel = new UsersRegisterUserViewModel {UserTypes = new List<SelectListItem>()};

    usersRegisterUserViewModel.UserTypes.Add(new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = "Select a registration type",
        Value = "0"
    });

    foreach (UserTypesDto userTypeDto in userTypes)
    {
        usersRegisterUserViewModel.UserTypes.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = userTypeDto.UserType,
            Value = userTypeDto.UserTypeId.ToString()
        });
    }

    return PartialView("_RegisterModal", usersRegisterUserViewModel);
}
```

Now based on the type of customer / userType they choose I need to present different views. Should not have any issue getting the view into the modal as it is ajax... So lets call this a pseudo wizard to collect data. The issue I am having and the basis for this probably simple question, that I am thinking too much about, is how do I save the data from each step?? Temp Table? InMemory Cache using the session id as the key? Cookies? "Gross"

The ActionMethod that the post goes to looks like this.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(UsersRegisterUserViewModel usersRegisterUserViewModel)
{
    //TODO Return a view for the next step based on the CustomerType contained in the viewModel
    return View();
}
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using TempData collection. It persists data only for the next request to come from the user.

Comment: TempData uses Session. Client won't allow session variables. It looks like I could potentially have 3 steps.

Comment: Still waiting on a good answer

Comment: Well @Romias has a good answer. But you can also use browser's local storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OPTION 1:**

The easiest way, is that the NEXT view have a set of `hidden` fields with the information entered in the previous view and which was posted to the Action.

This way, once you post the second view, you will be posting all the information (previous one and the one you entered in the second view).

**OPTION 2:**

If you are not comfortable with the first approach, you can have several PartialViews that are shown or hidden in javascript on UserType combo changes. Your ViewModel should have all the propertied you need to hold the information before posting back to server.

This option came in 2 flavors: you render all your usertype partials at the begining (so you need to hide them at first), or you can get the partial via Ajax once the user selected one user type.

**OPTION 3:**

You can use Session to hold the sensitive data from the register form, redirect to the next view depending on user type, post the new form, and in the Action you retrieve the information from Session... and with all the information in your hands store it in database.

Comment: Not comfortable with storing username and password combos in a hidden field though. I understand that is the easy way, just doesn't seem right.

Comment: OK, that is not the best in your case. So... you need to get the additional view, using Ajax... and place the view inside your main form.

Comment: Yes, I am using ajax to return the appropriate view to my modal window, just trying to figure out how to save the data from the first step. Once the first view is posted to the controller the data is gone / not available to the returned PartialView.

Comment: But the approach should be posting the information just one time, so, the ajax call just get a partial view, and you place it in a div, not replacing your main view. Then, you POST all the info at once.

Comment: If no Session is allowed, then OPTION 2 is the one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using razor, persist the different parts of your model like this

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.data1)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.data2) @*Wizard part 1*@
```

then in the next view for your wizard

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.data1)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.data2)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.data3)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.data4) @*Wizard part 2*@
```

and then

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.data1)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.data2)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.data3)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.data4)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.data5) @*Wizard part 3...*@
```

and so on...

Comment: Please see response to Romias answer.